# windows phone done and cancel buttons

Tags: windows-phone-8, custom-controls, timespan, cancel-button

Is it possible to access the built in 'done' and 'cancel' buttons to check which was touched/clicked. I am using the timeSpanPicker control and want to check if, when the control has been tapped, the user has confirmed a new time span or cancelled it?

Comment: Can you please post your code. I have no idea what you mean by the built in 'done' and 'cancel' buttons

Comment: It was the done button on the applicationbar that I was meaning but I sorted it out, sorry for the lack of code, will remember next time, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

When you pick a new value and tap the done applicationbar button the value changed event is raised. That's how you know a new value has been selected.